# What is the name of a repair shop specialized in fixing flat tires?

Tags: single-word-requests

Here in Brazil we have "borracharias" a repair shop with many tires where they replace or fix flat tires. "Borracha" means rubber. Neither Google Translate nor Wikipedia could help me to find an English translation for "borracharia".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the USA, Japan, and Taiwan, four types of shops specialize in fixing flat tires:

> Tire stores
>   Gasoline stations that also have shops that repair cars or motorcycles
>   Auto repair shops
>   Motorcycle repair shops

In Japan, though, you usually can't get a flat tire on a motorcycle repaired at an automobile repair shop, and in Taiwan, there are so many motorcycle repair shops that you wouldn't want to take your bike to an auto repair shop to have the tire fixed.

I can't think of a single English word used to describe these places.

Comment: Bill, in the US, none of those four types of shops actually specialize in fixing flat tires.  In every one of them, the main line of work is something else – eg selling tires, selling gasoline, doing engine repairs.  In all of them, repairing flats is a tiny fraction of their work, and not at all something they specialize in

Comment: @jwpat7: True, none of them are like the "sticky tape" tape shops from the original Saturday Night Live. But where else would you go to get a flat tire fixed? Not even the borracharias in Brazil make most of their money from repairing tires but from selling them. Maybe they make a lot of $ from retreading truck tires, though.

Answer (score 6):

There is no single English name for a repair shop specializing in fixing flat tires, as Bill points out.
Names for business types, like names for food. are intensely cultural and vary widely from locality to locality, and thus from language to language.

In English one only finds names for businesses that are commonly encountered in Anglophone areas. This is just as local as anywhere else. In Mexico, for instance, to refinish a desk, one buys varnish at a *tlapateria* but new drawer pulls at a *ferreteria*; in the U.S. one buys both at a *hardware store*.

There are stores in Mexico that just don't exist in the U.S, like a *refaccionaria*, where one buys spare parts (*refacciones* -- in Mexico; in Guatemala *refacciones* means 'snacks'). They stock spare parts for just about anything, from cars to kitchen blenders. There's nothing like that in the U.S.

Answer (score 1):

In the UK the general term is *garage*, which can mean 3 things:

A building next to your house where you keep your car;
What Americans call a gas station, ie a place selling fuel;
Any place where mechanics work repairing and servicing cars.

In the UK tyre repairs are dominated by a few well known national companies so you'd be more likely to say 'I took my car to  - [name of company]. Some of these deal only with tyres, others do other repairs. If you're talking of a small, privately owned repair shop you would probably call it a garage.

And yes, we do spell 'tyre' with a 'y'. 'Tire' is, you know, tired. Zzzzzzz.

Comment: That's true in the US as well, though none of them specialize in fixing flat tires, and some of them will fix any flat tire for free as a device to sell more tires.

Comment: "Tyre repair" firm/company/shop would be the closest in British English, and searching for that term turns up lots of the well known companies alluded to by Mynamite.

Comment: Trevor D's suggestion is the translation offered by the Oxford Spanish-English dictionary for the Spanish equivalent (*vulcanizadora*) of the Portuguese word in the question.